# How can I get the name of the parent folder of the current file in a Visual Studio Code snippet?

Tags: syntax, vscode-snippets

With or , you can insert the value of a variable. When a variable isn't set, its **default** or the empty string is inserted. When a variable is unknown (that is, its name isn't defined) the name of the variable is inserted and it is transformed into a placeholder.``` $name``${name:default} ```

The following variables can be used:

- `TM_SELECTED_TEXT` The currently selected text or the empty string
- `TM_CURRENT_LINE` The contents of the current line
- `TM_CURRENT_WORD` The contents of the word under cursor or the empty string
- `TM_LINE_INDEX` The zero-index based line number
- `TM_LINE_NUMBER` The one-index based line number
- `TM_FILENAME` The filename of the current document
- `TM_FILENAME_BASE` The filename of the current document without its extensions

so，what  `the parent folder of the current file` is ?

This my snipests codes

```json
"C C++ Header": {
        "scope": "c, cpp",
        "prefix": "h",
        "description": "Add #ifndef, #define and #endif",

        "body": [
            "#ifndef __${RELATIVE_FILEPATH/[\\/]/_/g}_${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)/${1:/upcase}/}_H__",
            "#define __${RELATIVE_FILEPATH/(.*)/${1:/upcase}/}_${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)/${1:/upcase}/}_H__",
            "",
            "$0",
            "",
            "#endif  //__${RELATIVE_FILEPATH/(.*)/${1:/upcase}/}_${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)/${1:/upcase}/}_H__"
        ]
    }
```

but useless for upcase the characater and translate the "/" to "_"

under is resultant

```
#ifndef __week03_Game_map.h_MAP_H__
#define __WEEK03/GAME/MAP.H_MAP_H__



#endif  //__WEEK03/GAME/MAP.H_MAP_H__
```

I want :

```
#ifndef __GAME_MAP_H__
#define __GAME_MAP_H__



#endif  //___GAME_MAP_H__
```